# GetSaveAsFilename method excel don't save my file

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

I have this code:

```
        app = new Application();
        app.Visible = false;
        workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
        worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
        worksheet.Name = "TEST";
        doSomethingInXLS();

        app.GetSaveAsFilename("TEST", "Excel (*.xls), *.xls", 1, "Save TEST", Missing.Value);
```

If I put Visible = true then I can see the excell is being generated correctly, but when I call the method GetSaveAsFilename, the save dialog show me, but the file is not saved, Why?

Comment: You are simply calling function from comdlg32.dll which actually does not save a file, only displays UI :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's what the method does:

> "Displays the standard Save As dialog box and gets a file name from
>   the user without actually saving any files."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195748%28v=office.11%29.aspx

To save the file you should get the filename that the method returns and use that to save the workbook.